# How to convert image to 8 bit depth in android ? I have tried many solution available on stack overflow but nothing is working

Tags: android, image, image-processing, bitmapimage

I have tried this and all Bitmap.Config option but nothing is working for me.

```
 int width, height;
    height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
    width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();    
    Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, 
    Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(0);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    paint.setColorFilter(f);
    c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
```

Comment: You want to convert it to grayscale or just reduce the color fidelity to at most 256 different colors?

Comment: convert image to grayscale and also bit depth to 8 bit

Comment: @SayyedShahbazAli Did you find a solution?